# Conditional entropy of linear transformation of random variables

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Let $X,Y,Z$ be $n-$dimensional random vectors such that $Z=AX+AY$ where $A$ is a $n\times n$ linear transformation matrix. Let $\det(A)=1$ where $\det(A)$ stands for determinant of $A$. Let $X\perp \!\!\! \perp Y$ and let $H(X)$ be the entropy of $X$. Then:

> Is this true: $H(AX|Z)=H(AX|AX+AY)=H(X|X+Y)\tag{1}$?

I know that $H(AX)=H(X)+\log(\det(A))$. So I was thinking of writing conditional entropy in terms of total entropy:

\begin{align*}
H(AX,Z) &= H(Z) + H(AX|Z) \text{ By chain rule } \\
&= H(AX+AY) + H(AX|AX+AY) \\
\implies H(AX|AX+AY) &= H(AX,AX+AY)-H(AX+AY) \\
&= H(AX,AX+AY)-H(X+Y)-\log(\det(A)) \\
&= H(AX,AX+AY)-H(X+Y) \text{ Since $\det(A)=1$}
\end{align*}

But I am not sure if the joint entropy $H(AX,AX+AY)=H(X,X+Y)$? If the previous line is true, then $(1)$ follows. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true quite generically. Let $(X,Z)$ be an arbitrary pair of random variables with a reasonably nice joint density $p_{XZ}$. Recall that $$ h(X|Z) = -\int p_{XZ}(x,z) \log \frac{p_{XZ}(x,z)}{p_Z(z)} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}z$$

By the standard transformation of random variables, for any invertible $A$, if $(U,V) = (AX, AZ) = B(X,Z),$ where $B = \mathrm{diag}(A,A)$ is a block diagonal matrix with blocks $A$, then $$ p_{UV}(u,v) = |\det B|^{-1} p_{XZ}(A^{-1} u, A^{-1}v).$$ Further, due to block diagonality, observe that $\det B = \det^2 A$.

By an idential calculation, $p_V(v) = |\det A|^{-1} p_Z(A^{-1}v)$

Thus, \begin{align}
h(U|V) &= -\int p_{UV}(u,v) \log \frac{p_{UV}(u,v)}{p_V(v)} \mathrm{d}u \mathrm{d}v \\ 
&\overset{(u,v) = B(x,z)}{=} -\int p_{UV}(Ax, Az) \log \frac{p_{UV}(Ax, Az)}{p_V(Az)} |\det B| \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}z\\
&= -\int p_{XY}(x,z) \log \frac{p_{XY}(x,z) |\det B|^{-1}}{p_Z(z) | \det A|^{-1}}
\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}z \\ &= h(X|Z) + \log |\det A|,\end{align} where I've used that $|\det B| = |\det A|^2$.

Your case follows on setting $X = X$ and $Z = (X+Y)$ and $\det A = 1$ in the above calculation (I chose slightly wrong notation in the beginning, because I thought that you defined $Z = X+Y$ instead of $Z = A(X+Y)$. There was too much to edit when I realised the notational snafu, so we get some mismatch. My apologies).

Notice that we made no assumptions about the joint law of $(X,Z)$ (besides regularity assumptions like $p(x,z)/p(z)$ have integrable logarithm), or about $A$ besides the fact that it is invertible. All that is really happening in this situation is that you're blowing up two random vectors with $A$, which is changing the common scale of the problem by a factor of $A$.

Comment: Thanks, I did not understand notation a bit and also don't remember transformation of r.v's, so bear with me. I think $U:=AX,V:=AZ$. May I know what kind of an object $(U,V)$ is because I didn't understand what you mean by $B(X,Z)$. $B$ is a matrix, so is $(X,Z)$ a matrix or a vector?

Comment: I guess I should have written $(U^T, V^T)^T = B (X^T, Z^T)^T,$ where for row vectors, by $(u,v)$ I mean the concatenation of $u$ and $v$. Maybe it's clearer if I just write $\begin{pmatrix} U \\ V \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & A \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} X \\ Z \end{pmatrix}$. Here, again, I'm using the standard notation of stacking two vectors to mean their concatenation.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now! Also, may I know that if $V=AZ$, then is $p_V(v)=|\det(A)|^{-1}p_Z(A^{-1}v)$ a known thing? I am used to finding distribution of transformation of a random variable by change of variables, so I see $z=A^{-1}v$ corresponds to change of variable but not sure where $|\det(A)|^{-1}$ came from? Thanks.

Comment: Yup this is just multivariate change of variables - for example see this http://ece-research.unm.edu/bsanthan/ece340/note1.pdf . High level (and being somewhat sloppy) reason is this - if you look at a small region around $z$, this has the probability $p_Z(z)|\mathrm{d}z|,$ where $|\mathrm{d}z|$ is the volume of a small region around $z$. This probability has to be conserved under the transformation, so if $v = Az,$ then $p_V(v) |\mathrm{d}v| = p_Z(z) | \mathrm{d}z|$. Now it's a multivariate calculus problem - we can write $z = A^{-1}v$, and we need to

Comment: (contd) relate $|\mathrm{d}(A^{-1} v)|$ to $|\mathrm{d}v|.$ This relation is expressed via the determinant of the Jacobian of the transformation $v \mapsto A^{-1}v$ (the Jacobian is just a local linearisation of the transformation. The determinant is entering due to the volume interpretation of determinants, i.e. $\det A$ is the volume of the parallelopiped induced by vectors of the columns of $A$). Because $v \mapsto A^{-1} v$ is already linear, its Jacobian is just $A^{-1}$, and then $\det A^{-1} = (\det A)^{-1}$ is standard.